# Windows 7's clipboard is erased on his own when I copy an url

Tags: windows-7, clipboard, url

I have an issue on a PC in my client office.
When I copy a URL from Internet Explorer (URL bar or inside a page), a new tab is opened and the clipboard is erased.

I tried with other web browsers, it's the same except that the new tab is opened in the default browser.

I also tried a clipboard manager, still the same.

I haven't found any weird software on any of the PC.

Comment: Does it do it in Safe Mode?

Answer (score 1):

> I haven't found any weird software on any of the PC.

You need to keep looking.

I am not aware of such a *feature* in Windows 7 itself. So I doubt it is to blame here.

I also doubt it's a browser feature, as the behavior seems to be browser independent and system-wide.

### OK, so what should I look for?

I did a quick search to see what applications might make use of such a feature. Maybe you'll recognize something.

1. Note taking
   Applications that automatically record URLs, so you can look at them later on.
   Example: [Logix Clipboard URL Monitor](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Office-tools/Clipboard/Logix-Clipboard-URL-Monitor.shtml)
2. Download managers
   Applications (or browser extensions) that want to help you manage your downloads.
   Example: [IDM Download Manager](http://www.internetdownloadmanager.com/support/clipboard_links.html) and [FlashGet](http://www.flashget.com/doc/addjob.htm)
3. Clipboard Enhancement
   Applications that somehow *extend* the functionality of the default clipboard.
   Example: [Clipboard Monitor](http://bexonet.com/Clipboard-Monitor.html) and [Launch Clipboard](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/launch-clipboard/)

Comment: Is there any program that could monitor this ?

Comment: @eephyne: I added some examples for you. Good luck hunting :)